# how to add multiple folder for store filestream

Tags: sql-server

As you know that Filestreams feature was introduced in SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2012 introduces new improvement 
where we can now add more than one container in same filegroup (containing filestream).Im my application i have used large 
number of file streams in various tables.So i have mapped filestream to local folder as

CREATE DATABASE NorthPole
ON
PRIMARY (

```
  NAME = NorthPoleDB,

  FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleDB.mdf'
```

), FILEGROUP NorthPoleFS CONTAINS FILESTREAM(

```
  NAME = NorthPoleFS,

FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleFS')
```

LOG ON (

```
  NAME = NorthPoleLOG,

FILENAME = 'C:\Temp\NP\NorthPoleLOG.ldf')
```

GO

.But now i want to map multiple folder for multiple table.This can improve IO, which can be spread across multiple directories / volumes / physical devices.
Let me know if you have any idea.